# How to get my countdown timer to reset to every time the view loads?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, delegates, viewcontroller

In my iOS quiz app you get 15 seconds to answer a question. If answered correctly, a second view controller appears than is dismissed from the click of the button on the second view controller and the first view controller reappears with a new question to be answered. However, the countdown timer is starting as soon as you click the answer to the question and not when you click the button on the second view controller to dismiss the second view controller. I want the countdown timer to reset soon as the button on the second view controller is dismissed and shows the original view controller with a new question. What's the best way to make this happen?

Here's my code (first view controller):

```
import UIKit

extension ViewController: QuizCompletedDelegate {
    func continueQuiz() {
        questionTimer.text = String(counter)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //random image func
    func randomImage() {
        index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questionImages.count)))
        questionImage.image = questionImages[index]
    }

    var questionList = [String]()

    func updateCounter() {
        counter -= 1
        questionTimer.text = String(counter)

        if counter == 0 {            
            timer.invalidate()
            wrongSeg()
        }
    }

    func randomQuestion() {        
        //random question
        if questionList.isEmpty {
            questionList = Array(QADictionary.keys)
            continueQuiz()            
        }

        let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questionList.count)))
        questionLabel.text = questionList[rand]

        //matching answer values to go with question keys
        var choices = QADictionary[questionList[rand]]!

        questionList.remove(at: rand)

        //create button
        var button:UIButton = UIButton()

        //variables
        var x = 1
        rightAnswerBox = arc4random_uniform(4)+1

        for index in 1...4
        {
            button = view.viewWithTag(index) as! UIButton

            if (index == Int(rightAnswerBox))
            {
                button.setTitle(choices[0], for: .normal)
            }
            else {
                button.setTitle(choices[x], for: .normal)
                x += 1    
            }   
            randomImage()
            continueQuiz()
        }
    }

    let QADictionary = ["Who is Thor's brother?" : ["Atum", "Loki", "Red Norvell", "Kevin Masterson"], "What is the name of Thor's hammer?" : ["Mjolinr", "Uru", "Stormbreaker", "Thundara"], "Who is the father of Thor?" : ["Odin", "Sif", "Heimdall", "Balder"]]

    //wrong view segue
    func wrongSeg() {        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "incorrectSeg", sender: self)        
    }

    //proceed screen
    func rightSeg() {    
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "correctSeg", sender: self)
    }

    //variables
    var rightAnswerBox:UInt32 = 0
    var index = 0

    //Question Label
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

    //Answer Button
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerBox))
        {
            rightSeg()
            print ("Correct!")
        }

        if counter != 0 {

        }
        else if (sender.tag != Int(rightAnswerBox)) {
            wrongSeg()
            print ("Wrong!")
            timer.invalidate()
            questionList = []
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        randomQuestion()
    }

    //variables
    var counter = 15

    var timer = Timer()

    @IBOutlet weak var questionTimer: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target:self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)        
    }
```

Code to second view controller:

```
import UIKit

protocol QuizCompletedDelegate {
    func continueQuiz()
}

class ContinueScreen: UIViewController {

    var delegate: QuizCompletedDelegate?

    //correct answer label
    @IBOutlet weak var correctLbl: UILabel!

    //background photo
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!

    func backToQuiz() {
        if let nav = self.navigationController {
            nav.popViewController(animated: true)    
        }
        else {
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func `continue`(_ sender: Any) {
        backToQuiz()
        delegate?.continueQuiz()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: If your second ViewController appears as show, rather than model, ViewDidLoad won't fire again because the view was still loaded in the background, and never unloaded. Use LukeSideWalkers solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the function viewDidAppear() on your first view controller, this function will be automatically called when your second viewcontroller is being dismissed and therefore the first will be seen (again).

So create this function in your first view controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // HERE PUT YOUR TIMER RESET
    // ...
}
```

Comment: My code already has such function that contains the function randomQuestion

Comment: You should call that method exactly where he typed "PUT YOUR TIMER RESET", and it will be called every time you return to this controller.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is in `buttonAction`. If the wrong answer is chosen, you `invalidate` the timer. However, if your answer is correct, you do nothing to the timer, and allow it to continue.

To pause a timer, you need to invalidate, then recreate it. So, what you can do is this:

```
//Answer Button
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerBox))
    {
        timer.invalidate() // Pause the current timer
        rightSeg()
        print ("Correct!")
    }

    if counter != 0 {

    }
    else if (sender.tag != Int(rightAnswerBox)) {
        wrongSeg()
        print ("Wrong!")
        timer.invalidate()
        questionList = []
    }
}
```

To create the timer again, you would need to add:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target:self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

You would add this timer when the view appears:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target:self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateCounter), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
```

Note that if you add a timer in `viewDidAppear`, you should remove the timer in `viewDidLoad`, otherwise you will create two timers when your application loads.

Upon removing the timer from viewDidLoad, the function should now look like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

 }
```

In summary, the idea here is: when you get the correct answer, you want to pause the timer (using timer.invalidate), then when the view appears, you would create a new timer.

Comment: How would I removed the time in the `viewDidLoad` section?